# perl system call script from C daemon causes to the perl script to crash

Tags: c, perl, system, daemon

I'm using CentOS 6.5.
I have a perl script that inside the script I have system call : 
`system("echo 1234 > /tmp/1.txt");`
the perl script is called by a daemon using `execv` command.
the problem is that when the perl script reaches to this system call ,the script crashes. when looking a the forked proccess I see it .
I tried to use eval on the system call inside the perl script but it still crashes.
I have few hosts with the same OS exactly , but this problem happens only on this specific machine.
When running the perl script manually , it works fine.
The daemon is running with root, same as all the other hosts I have.
Any help will be appriciated.

thanks guys.

EDIT :
There is no error message or what so ever , if there was some error it was easier.
any way here is the relevant piece of the code :

Daemon (wrote in C):

```
char command[2048];
sprintf(command, "./run.pl ");
char *args[] = {"sudo", "-u", user, "bash","-c",command,NULL};
execv("/usr/bin/sudo",args);
```

Perl script (run.pl) :

```
system("echo 1234 > /tmp/1.txt");
```

Comment: We need more information than that to be able to answer.

Comment: @Sobrique such as  ?

Comment: Some code. Some error messages. See [ask] for what makes a good question.

Comment: @Sobrique added more info , though I don't see the importance and how it isi related to the problem , I can not get any error when it crashes..

Comment: It's important and related, because we're not psychic - we cannot see your system, we don't know what it's doing. So in order to have a chance of troubleshooting, we need a detailed explanation of what's happening and what's going wrong.

Comment: @Sobrique ok , anyway , I put the codee in the main thread

Comment: How do you know the script crashes? What do you mean by "crash"? A segfault? How did you look at the forked process? Have you tried to attach a debugger to the script's process?

Comment: @nwellnhof I assume it crashes , I cant be really sure . what I do know that the perl script runs till the point it need to run the system function because I added some print message to the perl script before the system call. I don't really know how to check if it has a segfault. I did not attach debugger (don't know how to ) . I know that the main program started the process because I can see in the process list defunct process under the main program process. I hope you can lead me to a solution ... don't know where to look for..

Comment: Look at the documentation for your system() call and that might answer your question about how to capture any faults.

Comment: @tale852150 nothing there

Comment: This is not a solution to your question but I wanted to post this for you to help in any way I can, especially with regard to my last comment about looking at the system() perldoc documentation.  Use the last code stub shown at the bottom of the perldoc page (see link below) to help determine what may be causing your issue. 

http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html

Comment: @tale852150 thank you , didn't help though. I found other solution, though I am not sure why it is working..

Comment: Well at least it is working now. :-)

Answer (score 1):

So , I found really strange solution , don't know why - but it works..
in the command argument in the C program, I put my stdout to /dev/null . 
strange , but works.

```
char command[2048];
sprintf(command, "./run.pl > /dev/null");
char *args[] = {"sudo", "-u", user, "bash","-c",command,NULL};
execv("/usr/bin/sudo",args);
```

Comment: Did the daemon close stdout instead of redirecting it to /dev/null?